# (Swift) Question regarding Notification trigger

Tags: swift, rest, notifications

How can I change up my code to allow my notification to trigger every 12 hours since the last API call. In the code, you can see where I commented out the variable containing the last API call (lastRefreshDate)

```
// let lastRefreshDate = userDefaults.object(forKey: Constants.Defaults.LATEST_REQUEST_TIME) as? Date
        var dateComponents = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current, hour: 12, minute: 0)

        
        if let date = UserDefaults.getDate() {
            dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)
         
        }
        
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
        
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "reminder", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        center.add(request) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what the question is here. There is no "every 12 hours" option in iOS notifications. (Nothing will ensure that your app launches at some particular time.) But you can request the next notification to be 12 hours from now. Your current code requests the next notification at noon. If you want 12 hours from now, you need to compute 12 hours from now (`date(byAdding:to:options:)`). Is there a deeper question?

Comment: Echo Rob's comment.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a push notification to go out every 12 hours by using the time the API gets called as the start time. Hopefully, that explains it a little better and is doable